# 店長に休みたいならそう言えと言われた。 - What does the そう represent here?

Tags: meaning

> 店長に休みたいならそう言えと言われた。

What does the そう represent here? As far as I know, there are 2 uses of そう

1. replace the ます stem to mean seems like.
2. End of a 普通形 to represent something that you heard from somewhere / someone.

Can someone explain what the indicated そう means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That そう is neither of them, but an adverb.

- [そのように。](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86/#jn-127918)

So...it translates ***so***.

---

First note there are quotes omitted: 店長に「休みたいならそう言え」といわれた. Now consider 休みたいならそう言え.

From a learner's point of view, you can get the translation as follows

- 休みたい *want to rest / want a day off*
- なら *if* (although it means more *then*)
- そう *so*
- 言え *say* in the imperative

Combined, *If you want a day off, say so*.

---

FYI: Another fairly common phrase is

- そう思います *I think so.*

Comment: Good answer.  Just in case someone is still unsure, 休みたいなら**そう**言え ＝ 休みたいなら「休みたい」と言え.  Think of it as a way to avoid repeating 休みたい.

Comment: @fynxgloire, you can think of the そう here as very much like the English "so" -- **そう**言え == _"say **so**"_.